# Protractor/Jasmine timeout when running multiple test suites

Tags: testing, ionic2, protractor, angularjs-e2e

I just started writing tests for an Ionic application.
So far, I've written 2 tests, each one in its own `.js` file.

If each test is ran separately, it works perfectly. If I put both tests in the same file, they work too.

But, when I have 2 test files, each one with its own `describe` function, I always get a timeout between the tests.

Error message is `Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.`

This is my `protractor.js` file:

```
exports.config = {
capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome',
    'chromeOptions': {
        args: ['--disable-web-security']
    }
},
baseUrl: 'http://localhost:8100',
specs: [
    'tests/*.js'
],
jasmineNodeOpts: {
    isVerbose: true,
    showColors: true,
    includeStackTrace: true,
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 10000
},
allScriptsTimeout: 200000,
onPrepare: function() {
    browser.driver.get(browser.baseUrl);
}
```

};

What should I do in order to be able to have my tests organised in multiple files?

Comment: Have you tried increasing default timeout interval to a higher value as the error mentions.

Comment: Can you also post a piece of your steps code?

Comment: @Grasshopper, @wswebcreation, sorry it took me long. It seems the browser session was not cleared between tests. The second one was timing out because it started waiting for an element to be available, using `browser.wait()`.  I was able to run multiple tests using `restartBrowserBetweenTests: true` in Protractor's config and `browser.ignoreSynchronization` in each test. Not sure what implications are there.